# How to create points in split of line feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I had a point features shapefile and line feature shapefile. I created a new shapefile by splitting line feature with those points. Now, I lost the point shapefile. Is there anyway I can create point feature from line feature? I don't want vertices at every corners. I just want them at end of each line feature.

Comment: I need to have points on the line which I splitted using point shapefile before.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about ArcMap or QGIS in this particular question.

Comment: I edited the question to just arcmap. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a point layer from a line in QGIS using the 'extract vertices' tool: Vector | Geometry tools | Extract vertices from the menu bar, or search for the tool using the locate functionality (ctrl-K or cmd-K).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't want vertices at every corners. I just want them at endd of each line feature.

Comment: @AASHISHSHARMA Please click 'edit' on your original post and explain this. This answer does solve your problem as stated.